# How to link to shared lib in c++

Tags: c++, makefile, shared-libraries, zeromq

Could someone help me with linking to a shared lib, specifically libzmq, in C++?

```
all: clean compile                                        

clean:                                                    
    rm bin *.o -f                                         

compile:                                                  
    g++ -g -Wall -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib main.cpp -lzmq -o bin
```

I've installed libzmq using the following steps:

```
git clone https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq.git
cd libzmq
./autogen.sh
./configure
make && sudo make install
```

Here's my main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>                                                       
#include <string>                                                         

#include <zmq/zmq.h>                                                    

// Required by fork routine                                               
#include <sys/types.h>                                                    
#include <unistd.h>                                                       

// Required by wait routine                                               
#include <sys/wait.h>                                                     

#include <stdlib.h>         // Declaration for exit()                     
#include <cstdio>           // printf                                     
using namespace std;                                                      

int global_variable = 2;                                                  

int main(int argc, char** argv){                                          
    const short int FORK_FAILED = -1;                                     
    const short int FORK_SUCCESS = 0;                                     
    int stack_variable = 20;                                              
    pid_t pid;                                                            
    string status_identifier;                                             
    switch (pid = fork()){                                                
        case FORK_SUCCESS:                                                
            printf("Child changing global and stack variables\n");        
            global_variable++;                                            
            stack_variable++;                                             
            break;                                                        
        case FORK_FAILED:                                                 
            cerr << "Failed!  -- Failed to fork:  " << pid << endl;       
            exit(1);                                                      
        default:                                                          
            printf("Child process (pid=%d) created successfully.\n", pid);
            wait(0);                                                      
            break;                                                        
    }                                                                     
    printf("[pid=%d] Global:  %d\n", pid, global_variable);               
    printf("[pid=%d] Stack:  %d\n", pid, stack_variable);                 
    return 0;                                                             
}
```

And, here's the error msg:

```
bitcycle @ ubuntu64vm ~/git/test $ make
rm bin *.o -f
g++ -g -Wall -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib main.cpp -lzmq -o bin
main.cpp:4:23: fatal error: zmq/zmq.hpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [compile] Error 1
```

The error is pretty straight forward, but I've yet to find a solution.  Any ideas?

My goal is to do something like [this](http://zguide.zeromq.org/cpp%3ahwclient) with multiple child processes.

**Update**  I'm just going to install it system-wide in ubuntu:  `sudo apt-get install libzmq-dev`, and that resolved the issue.  It doesn't teach me anything about how to identify a shared lib and header file on disk and link to it... but I guess I can move that to another day.

Comment: That's not a link error. 'Tis a compiler error, specifically a failure to find your header file. Double check your include paths.

Comment: Are you sure there is a `zmq/` subdirectory in `/usr/local/include`? In `libzmq-dev` on debian, there is no such subdirectory, you just directly `#include <zmq.hpp>`

Comment: @AntonKovalenko -- I installed libzmq from source, as described in the "how I installed libzmq" section above.

Comment: I've read what you've written. The point is, distros usually *don't* move header files when packaging stuff, unless they have a strong reason to. That's why there are big chances to find `zmq.hpp` under `/usr/local/include` without intermediate `zmq/` directory.

Comment: @WhozCraig -- So, `zmq.h` (not `zmq.hpp`, I've since corrected that) is found here:  `/usr/local/include/zmq.h`.  And, I'm adding that in my make file here:  `-I/usr/local/include`.  Is that not correct?

Comment: But the code says `#include <zmq/zmq.h>`, which expects there to be a `zmq` directory somewhere.

Comment: @bitcycle Read Bo's comment. You need `#include <zmq.h>` in your source file. *There is no `zmq/zmq.h` because there is no `zmq` folder off any folders in your include path with a file in it called `zmq.h`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ wrapper for ZeroMQ (zmq.hpp) is no longer part of ZeroMQ. There is no zmq.hpp in current libzmq master or in latest stable 3.2.x.